# How can I save state for a `CpuPool` worker thread?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm creating a `futures_cpupool::CpuPool` where each thread needs to open database connections, a costly initialization. The state of these initializations need to persist between jobs because they take so long to set up. The database connections are necessary for the worker threads to complete their jobs.

Comment: Note: `CpuPool` is intended for intense CPU work, most notably because it blocks the thread for the whole duration, as such, using network connections during said work is not recommended.

Comment: I don't understand why it's a problem that it blocks the whole thread @MatthieuM.

Comment: It's a scalability issue if you have long-lived transactions: you'll need more threads. CpuPool is designed for CPU-bound tasks, using it for anything else might be suboptimal... though of course it might be good enough for you.

Comment: Why not just use an existing database connection pool library like [r2d2](https://crates.io/crates/r2d2)?

Comment: I wrote a crate (https://crates.io/crates/scoped_stateful_threadpool) for this, although it doesn't support futures.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: there might be a better solution leveraging some `CpuPool` API, maybe...*

A simple solution would be to use a separate `ConnectionPool`, shared with `Arc`.

Then, you simply hand over a reference to the `ConnectionPool` whenever you start a thread and ask them to acquire a connection from there.

The pool itself will be in charge of:

- preparing new connections (performing the initialization work),
- recycling used connections so that further demands are met faster.

There is a slight difficulty here if the connection parameters are changed (for example, specifying a different locale). I recommend that each client be handed a "fresh" connection, with all settings normalized to a known value.

There is also a design choice for when (and on which thread) to perform the initialization and recycling work; I advise that you start with the simplest solution:

- initialization on demand,
- recycling immediately when handed over.

Comment: What crate is ConnectionPool in? This is also not an ideal solution, because there's no guarantee that one thread always gets the same connection. That's preferable behavior due to not requiring `Send` and having slightly better NUMA behavior.

Comment: @njaard: It's not a crate, you'll have to write it yourself. You are welcome to push in thread affinity if you think it matters, but honestly in a database connection the network part is so slow compared to cpu/memory that I would not even bother.